# dropdownlist auto select first value in gridview with edit mode

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, ispostback

actually I have bounded a dropdownlist in gridview in edit mode, but the problem is that whenever i try to select another value from dropdownlist, it auto select the first value.

I also used !IsPostBack  property on page_load event but still it is not selecting the another items.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {

            DropDownList ddlCost_Code = DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCost_Code");

            BAL bl = new BAL();
            DataTable dt_for_CostCode = null;

            dt_for_CostCode = bl.Select_Cost_Code();
            if (dt_for_CostCode.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlCost_Code.DataSource = dt_for_CostCode;
                ddlCost_Code.DataTextField = "Cost_Code";
                ddlCost_Code.DataValueField = "Proposalno";
                ddlCost_Code.DataBind();
            }

}


  if (!IsPostBack)
    {


        try
        {

            Log_Booked_Info_Through_Booking_Table();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebMsgBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, this will be more efficent.

```
if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
{
     // your code here
}
```

> Secondly, check the `AutoPostBack` property of DropDown inside your gridview. What is it set to. It should be false in your case, unless you have some logic set on the `onselectedindexchanged` event of dropdown.

Comment: your code didn't give the solution. I need to make AutoPostBack property True because I need to do something on onselectedindexchanged  event.

Comment: sorry guys Actually I was forget to remove the page prerender event, which i write for some test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ddlCost_Code.SelectedIndex = 0;
```